# Short cut for adding more variable names in MAKE subcommand of VARSTOCASES in SPSS statistics 22

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

There are 150 variables in a spss file. If I want to keep 5 columns and unpivot rest 145 columns, what will be the spss code?
If Column names are col1,col2,col3.....col150

Instead of below code

```
VARSTOCVASES   
    /MAKE  VariableName1 FROM Col1 Col2 Col3 ..... Col145
    /INDEX=VariableName(VariableName1) 
    /KEEP=Col146 Col147 Col148 Col149 Col150
```

Any alternative code like below is there?(Below one just an example)

```
VARSTOCASES
    /MAKE  VariableName1 FROM ALL Except [Col146 Col147 Col148 Col149 Col150]
    /INDEX=VariableName(VariableName1) 
    /KEEP=Col146 Col147 Col148 Col149 Col150
```

Here I want a short cut to avoid adding all 145 variables in `MAKE` subcommand.

Here i only want to know if there is any simple way to mention all variables names in `MAKE` subcommand except 3 or 4 variables,otherwise i want to put all 145 names in `MAKE` subcommand.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read and understand the `VARSTOCASES` command help first. Based on this question and your previous question, I don't think you actually understand what this command does and what is its output.

Comment: @horace_vr: please leave about my previous question,according to my understanding we should specify all variable names,but i don't want to do like that if any short cuts are there then it will be easy for me.please leave about all other commands only i want to know MAKE command,,thanks..

Comment: If you need something more complex than `col1 to col145`, look up `SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES` extension command, which enables you to create a list of variables that fit some conditions - and then use the list in your `/make` command.

Comment: @eli-k:Can u give some syntax for selecting all variables except 2 or 3 variables

Comment: as @horace_vr said, there's way to directly ask SPSS to use "all variables except XYZ" - you have to create a workaround, for example using  SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES extension command. But you haven't answered - doesn't this work? `/make newvar from Col1 to Col145`

Comment: @eli-k:This will work only if the columns are in sequential order but i need random Columns like col1 col9 col22 col44 like this.

Comment: if you can define the properties of the variables that need to be on the list then probably it's possible to automate creation of the list. Maybe you should start a new question with more details about this specific part of the problem

Comment: @eli-k:I asked a new question about this problem

Answer (score 2):

In short - no. In the `\MAKE` subcommand of the `VARSTOCASES` command, you may specify variables one by one, or, if they are consecutive in the dataset, you can use the `T0` keyword:

`var_start TO var_end`

I am not aware of any way, in SPSS, to specify variables in a ("ALL, except some") format.

However, note one very important thing: in `VARSTOCASES` you cannot have the same variable(s) specified in both `MAKE` and `KEEP` subcommands. `MAKE` deals with the restructured variables, while `KEEP` and `DROP` deal with the variables not involved in the restructuring.

Comment: thanks for your help and i read the help document after your suggestion and i understood the concept.

Comment: I think this (var_start TO var_end) is for sequential order but i need to take random variables like col1 col9 col12 like this.